# Most Current Version and Further Development/ new Features

Tags: iphone, zxing, zbar

i am wondering since the last commit date I found on the page was from Aug 8, 2011, if the ZBar Lib is still up to date. I decided last year to go with Zbar because of the good voting on Stackoverflow.

I developed an iPhone app about one year ago. Now it is time for version 2.0 of this app. So I would like to know if I should continue with this library, or if it is time to switch to an alternative like ZXing?

Thx

Comment: You should contact the ZBar maintainers. Chances are that no, it's not up-to-date, given the updates to iOS in the last ~18 months.

Answer (score 2):

ZBar is still working for the all the OS I have recently used it, Zxing sometimes rejected by the apple while you submit App on AppStore.